# Filling a generic vector with random values

Tags: c++

I want write a function that fill a vector with random values.

T = numerical and Pnt struct.

**My Question :** How do I fill a vector of template with random values?

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class  Pnt{
public:
    int x, y;
    Pnt(int _x, int _y) :x(_x), y(_y){}
};
template <typename T>
void fill(vector<T>& vec){
   for (auto& value : vec)
    // how to fill with random values

}
int main() {
    vector<Pnt> arr_pnt(10);
    fill(arr_pnt);

    vector<int> arr_int(10);
    fill(arr_int);

    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:**

I have modified the code as shown below.Is there a way to do it by std::is_same inside the fill function?

```
class  Pnt{
public:
    int x, y;
    Pnt(int _x, int _y) :x(_x), y(_y){}
};
void getRnd(Pnt& p){
    p.x = rand();
    p.y = rand();
}
void getRand(int& value){
    value = rand();
}
template <typename T>
void fill(vector<T>& vec){
    for (auto& value : vec)
    getRand(value);


}
int main() {
    vector<Pnt> arr_pnt(10);
    fill(arr_pnt);

    vector<int> arr_int(10);
    fill(arr_int);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One component which seems to be missing is a random number generator. What have you tried?

Comment: Write a function that randomly generates one value, then use `std::generate`.

Comment: Under the circumstances, I'd probably use `std::generate_n` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to write your own fill method, use `std::generate` or `std::generate_n`.

```
// use of std::rand() for illustration purposes only
// use a <random> engine and distribution in real code
int main() {
    vector<Pnt> arr_pnt(10);
    std::generate(arr_pnt.begin(), arr_pnt.end(), [](){ return Pnt{std::rand(), std::rand()};});

    vector<int> arr_int;
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(arr_int), 10, std::rand);

    return 0;
}
```